# Adding mysql data in to HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a mysql database called `waterparamsdb` and a table called `waterparams`.
The table has 6 columns:

```
Temperature
Acidity
Ammonia
Nitrite
Nitrate
Phosphate
```

I use an HTML form to update the table with numbers.  This part works fine.  In PHPMYADMIN I see new rows with the information:

```
temperature ¦ acidity ¦ ammonia ¦ nitrite ¦ nitrate ¦ phosphate 
25.50 ¦ 7.60 ¦ 0.25 ¦ 0.00 ¦ 0.00 ¦ 1.00 
26.00 ¦ 7.80 ¦ 0.50 ¦ 0.25 ¦ 0.25 ¦ 2.00
```

I followed https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp example and was able to first get the information using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
$username = "redacted"; 
$password = "redacted"; 
$database = "waterparamsdb"; 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM waterparams";


echo '<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2"> 
      <tr> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">Temperature</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">Acidity</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">Ammonia</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">Nitrite</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">Nitrate</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">Phosphate</font> </td> 
      </tr>';

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $field1name = $row["col1"];
        $field2name = $row["col2"];
        $field3name = $row["col3"];
        $field4name = $row["col4"];
        $field5name = $row["col5"]; 
        $field5name = $row["col6"];

        echo '<tr> 
                  <td>'.$field1name.'</td> 
                  <td>'.$field2name.'</td> 
                  <td>'.$field3name.'</td> 
                  <td>'.$field4name.'</td> 
                  <td>'.$field5name.'</td> 
                  <td>'.$field6name.'</td>
              </tr>';
    }
    $result->free();
} 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine and displays the two rows of information in a plain format.  What I would like to do though is only output the last row's values in to a HTML table and display the information on the web page like this:

```
Temperature ¦ Value
Acidity ¦ Value
Ammonia ¦ Value
Nitrite ¦ Value
Nitrate ¦ Value
Phosphate ¦ Value
```

I've tried the following adapted from the website above, but it returns 0 results.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "redacted";
$password = "redacted";
$dbname = "waterparamsdb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, temperature FROM waterparams";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>Parameter</th><th>Value</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["temperature"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

I know this is likely just a simple understanding and formatting issue, I'm still learning!  If anyone is able to help, I would appreciate it greatly.  Thanks.

Comment: By "last row's values" do you mean the "newest" value?

Comment: Hi, yes sorry the newest value

Comment: If you got an `id` row you can add `ORDER BY id DESC` at the end of your query to have to highest value at the top and can simply take that one

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by `id` row?  Thanks

Comment: It was meant to be column, sorry. Add a new column called `id` and give every entity an id. You can set it to auto increment. By that you can always order them by the highest id and see which one is the newest. Date works too. (I hope you understand what I am trying to say)

Comment: Thanks.  I understand some!  I've managed to add an `id` column now using `ALTER TABLE waterparams ADD COLUMN id INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE FIRST;`.  Each row of values now has an id number.  The newest entry is the highest number.  Now just need to work out how to add that to my PHP

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM waterparams ORDER BY id DESC";` puts the highest id to the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your if loop like this

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>Temperature</th><th>Acidity</th><th>Ammonia</th><th>Nitrite</th><th>Nitrate</th><th>Phosphate
    </th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["Temperature"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Acidity"]."</td><td>" . $row["Ammonia"]."</td><td>" . $row["Nitrite"]."</td><td>" . $row["Nitrate"]."</td><td>" . $row["Phosphate"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

But make sure the value inside these `$row["Temperature"]` array should be correct column name

And change your sql query to this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM waterparams";
```

Comment: Thanks, but it returns `0 results`

Comment: bro can you show me your columns ? and did you modified the sql query ?? Check my answer once again as i've updated it now @Chrizh

Comment: Oh wait, I had to amend another line which was incorrect `$sql = "SELECT temperature, acidity, ammonia, nitrite, nitrate, phosphate FROM waterparams";` which now puts the data in a table!  Just need to work out how to pull only the newest values.

Comment: yeah  then modify this line $row['temperature'] also, make all column name lowercase in array @Chrizh

Comment: Just seen your update, I'll try the `*` instead, thanks that's helped a lot

Comment: Its my pleasure and make sure to watch for column name to make it appear in table @Chrizh